# SumRunning and Switch in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I run the following code and an error occurs

The code in stimulsoft

{Switch( SumRunning( DataSource1.num) > 0 ,"yes")}

Error:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Why???

Answer (score 0):

This error is already fixed. Upgrade to the latest build.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{IIF(SumRunning(DataSource1.num) > 0, "yes" , "No")}
```

If you use Switch, use this:

```
{Switch(CommonPayment.CheckStatus == 0, "وصول شده", 
CommonPayment.CheckStatus == 1, "در جریان وصول", 
CommonPayment.CheckStatus == 2, "برگشتی")}
```

This code is executed if `SumRunning(DataSource1.num)` returns the number.